# Agda: return the last element of a List

Tags: list, agda

When I check in `agda-stdlib/src/Data/List/Base.agda` I see that there is no `last` function but I see in `agda-stdlib/src/Data/Vec/Base.agda` a function for `last`.

When I try to use it though I get some type errors that I'm unsure I understand.

This is how I'm trying to call it:
`last (fromList todos)`

where

```
todos : List Todo
```

and

```
record Todo : Set where
  field
    text      : String
    completed : Bool
    id        : ℕ
```

The error I get is

```
Data.List.foldr (λ _ → suc) 0 todos != suc _n_31 of type ℕ
when checking that the expression fromList todos has type
Data.Vec.Vec Todo (1 + _n_31)
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that `last` has this signature:

```
last : ∀ {n} → Vec A (1 + n) → A
```

But I'm confused because when I do `C-c C-l` on:

```
last (fromList ?)
```

I get this goal

```
?0 : List Todo
```

which I thought `todos` satisfied.

What should I change here to make it pass this error?
Or is there another way to get the last element of a `List`?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried a different route and decided to replace the `Vec` with `List`. However I'm getting another error I don't quite understand when I try to do

```
  Todo.completed (last (todos ∷ʳ record { text = text ; completed = false ; id = 1 }))
≡⟨⟩
  Todo.completed (record { text = text ; completed = false ; id = 1 })
```

```
false !=
Todo.completed
(last
 (todos ∷ʳ record { text = text ; completed = false ; id = 1 })
 | Data.Vec.initLast
   (todos ∷ʳ record { text = text ; completed = false ; id = 1 }))
of type Bool
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  false ≡ _y_45
matches the expected type
  Todo.completed
  (last
   (todos ∷ʳ record { text = text ; completed = false ; id = 1 }))
  ≡ false
```

I'm not sure what the error message is saying here.

**EDIT**

I tried to simplify the problem down further to

```
AddNat : ∀ {n : ℕ} → (Vec ℕ n) → (Vec ℕ (1 + n))
AddNat numbers = numbers ∷ʳ 1

AddNatLastAddedElementIsNat :
  ∀ {n : ℕ} (numbers : Vec ℕ (1 + n)) →
    last (AddNat numbers) ≡ 1
AddNatLastAddedElementIsNat numbers =
  begin
    last (AddNat numbers)
  ≡⟨⟩
    last (numbers ∷ʳ 1)
  ≡⟨⟩
    1
  ∎
```

but I still get a similar error:

```
1 != (last (numbers ∷ʳ 1) | Data.Vec.initLast (numbers ∷ʳ 1)) of
type ℕ
when checking that the expression 1 ∎ has type
last (numbers ∷ʳ 1) ≡ 1
```

Why does the `last (numbers ∷ʳ 1)` show up as type `(last (numbers ∷ʳ 1) | Data.Vec.initLast (numbers ∷ʳ 1))`? Does `|` indicate it is a sum type and I would need to pattern match on both cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The goal in `fromList ?0` does have type `List Todo`, but since `fromList ?0` has type `Vec _ (length ?0)` you'll get an error if the typechecker concludes that there can't be no `n` such that `length ?0` is (definitionally) equal to `1 + n`.
In your case that happens once you say that `?0 := todos`, something like `?0 := x ∷ todos` would have worked instead.

Generally a function like `last` needs to know that the list or vectors is non-empty, an alternative is to define a function that returns `Maybe A` instead of `A` though.